# C while infinite loop print error

Tags: c, while-loop

I made counting little alphabet program.

However Unintentional result return.

[image: output]

I want "Please enter a character " to be printed once per loop.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#pragma warning (disable : 4996)

 int main() {
char a;
int b = 0, d = 0;

 while (1) {

    printf("Please enter a character <escape .>");
    scanf("%c", &a);

    if (a == '.')
        break;

    if (a <= 'a' || a >='z') {
        d = d + 1;
        continue;
    }

}

 printf ("Number of lower case letters %d", d);

getchar(); getchar(); getchar();
return 0;}
```

Please help me

Comment: I followed your advice and it works fine. Thank you for your kindness.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
scanf("%c", &a);
```

by

```
scanf(" %c", &a);
```

Whitespaces were getting consumed by scanf. The use of a blank space in scanf() before %c enables omitting whitespaces.

P.S. To detect lowercase alphabets, the actual if condition should be

```
if (a >= 'a' && a <='z')
```

Comment: P.P.S. To detect lowercase letters, there is a library function: [`islower`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/islower).

Comment: I followed your advice. and I got the result I wanted. Thank you for pointing out the wrong part.

Comment: If it works for you, please accept the answer. Click on the tick mark to the left side of the answer.

Comment: The condition should use && instead of ||    As in: 

    if ( a >= 'a' && a <=  'z' )